# Getting error as :TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

Below is the code snippet from App.js which includes the `Navigator` component:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <HeaderAmex className="App" />
          <div>
            <Navigation/>
          </div>
          <Route exact path="/invoice" component={Invoice} /> 
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(App)
```

My Navigation component looks like below. It gets the location as property:

```
class Navigation extends Component {
  render() {
    const { match, location, history } = this.props

    return (
      <Router>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <button
            className="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>    
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <NavDropdown name="Test">
                <a className="dropdown-item" >                  
                  <li><Link to={"/Invoice"} >Mexico Invoice</Link></li>
                </a>
              </NavDropdown>
              <NavDropdown name="Analysis">
                <a className="dropdown-item" href="/Transaction">Audit Log</a>
              </NavDropdown>
            </ul>
            <Route exact path="/Invoice" component={Invoice}  />
          </div>
        </nav>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Navigation)
```

Below is the code from Invoice.js

```
render() {
  const { match, location, history } = this.props
  console.log("---------------------------"+this.state.invoicedisplayFlag);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <br/>
      <label className="lable" style={{marginRight:19}}>
        InvoiceXml:
        <input
          type="text"
          name="invoiceXml"
          placeholder="Enter invoice xml"
          onBlur={this.handleChangeInvoice.bind(this)}
          style={{marginLeft:15}}
        />
      </label>
      <br/>
      <input
        type="button"
        onClick={this.handleSubmitInvoiceXml}
        name="Submit"
        value="Submit"
        className="submitButton"
        style={{marginLeft:-60}}
      />
      <br/>
      <div className={this.state.invoicedisplayFlag ? "showDisplay" : "hide"}>
        <h5>Transaction Id is :{this.state.invoiceTransId}</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am getting the error:

`"TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined" at Router.js:66`

I have tried multiple approach listed for this issue but nothing resolved my error. Can anybody please help me in the same?

Comment: You'll probably get more help if you indent your code correctly. This is very hard to read as it.

Comment: except for destructing location from props, there is no use of it in your code? so why are you destructing it?

Comment: and the Error is saying that yout `props` is not defined. debug to see what you get on props

Comment: i tried using that solution which was suggested for few,but it didn't help.

Comment: Even without destructing the props ,i was getting the same error

Comment: Where is the code of Router.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow,

I am not sure if I understand your problem correctly, since you're mostly showing code but nothing specific about the situation or location where your error occurs.

What I am seeing is that you're handing your `Invoice` component in the route via the `component` property. After reading [this github post](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4105#issuecomment-287262726) it seems that with react-router v4 you should use the `render` property to hand over props together with your component.

So basically what you should do is:

1. Create a function which takes props as a parameter and returns your Invoice component with the desired props
2. Change `<Route exact path="/Invoice" component={Invoice} />` to `<Route exact path="/Invoice" render={MyInvoiceFunction} />` in Navigator.js
3. Keep in mind to provide some more information and well formatted code on your next question ;)

Hopefully this solves your problem

EDIT:

You should add the function to your Invoice.js to like:

```
export const MyInvoiceFunction = (props) => {
  return (
    <Invoice match={this.match.bind(this)} location={this.location.bind(this)} {...props} />
  );
};
```

Comment: ...Do i need to add this function in Invoice component?